# Mongodb > 10 million documents realtime data visualization

Tags: database, mongodb, real-time

I'm building a telemetry app for my university's formula student car, and I need to visualize data in real time, this data is stored in a mongodb instance and is constantly being updated, at around 7000 documents per second it gets filled up pretty fast. The database usually contains about 50 million documents, so is it possible to visualize this data in realtime on a laptop? Or should I create another instance of mongodb and insert a document only every 100-500 milliseconds as to make queries faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using InfluxDB as my database because it's optimized for time series Data, combined with Grafana it is a great combination for displaying telemetry data at a high resolution.

Answer (score 1):

1. You may need to split the data in shards to scale the writes.
2. For the reads speed it is important to create suitable indexes and as much as possible RAM and storage IOPS.
3. Since this is telemetry data and few lost samples are probably not of a concern, you may speed writes additionally reducing writeConcern & journaling .

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your comment, I ended up switching  to influxDB, combined with grafana it seems to provide everything I need (aggregation window for auto resizing, querying on millions of documents of time series, etc)

Comment: Indeed influxDB/Grafana is one of the best for time series ... , mongoDB is best for scalable document storage